# some Hibernate Question

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 2 question 
I wanna make Mysql table that have  charset utf8 but I don't know where I shoud set the setting.
(I just have a hibernate.cfg.XMl no any .xml file for hibernate)
i dun want set mysql.ini file that default setting was UTF-8 I wanna put this setting in my hibernate.

second Question:
I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `buildingtel` (
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`buildingname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`tel` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`buildingname`,`tel`),
KEY `FK_buildingtel_2` (`buildingname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can i Map these to and Java entity
I can do like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "btel")
public class Btel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;;
@Column(name = "username", length=50)
private String username;
@Column(name = "buildingname", length=50)
private int buildingname;
@Column(name = "tel", length=15)
private int tel;
//some setter & getter
}
```

but i want to set (`username`,`buildingname`,`tel`) together as a primary key how I can do it by annotation in hibernate

TanX in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UTF-8:

```
<property name=”hibernate.connection.useUnicode”
value=”true” />
<property name=”hibernate.connection.characterEncoding”
value=”UTF-8″ />
```

---

As for setting a combined primary key, it is possible, but having worked with it I can say I wouldnt recommend it. From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier):

> You can define a composite primary key
>   through several syntaxes:
>
> - annotate the component property as @Id and make the component class
>     @Embeddable
> - annotate the component property as @EmbeddedId
> - annotate the class as @IdClass and annotate each property of the entity
>     involved in the primary key with @Id

This becomes a pain to work with, and it isn't the recommended way to do this in Hibernate.

What I would recommend instead is to use [the @NaturalId annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2201):

> While not used as identifier property,
>   some (group of) properties represent
>   natural identifier of an entity. This
>   is especially true when the schema
>   uses the recommended approach of using
>   surrogate primary key even if a
>   natural business key exists. Hibernate
>   allows to map such natural properties
>   and reuse them in a Criteria query.
>   The natural identifier is composed of
>   all the properties marked @NaturalId.